# Should I flag edited "thank you" posts?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11685821/857760) as "Not an answer" because it was just a "thank you" answer at that time, but has been edited before the moderator review (to a worse copy of the referenced post). The flag got declined. Should I flag for moderator attention in these situations?

Comment: What do you mean with "in these situations"? If you mean after the decline, no, just get on, such things happen. If you mean whether to flag answer such as that one, a somewhat harder call. That one specifically contained the code from the first revision on, so it may be viewed as an answer even before the edit. In general, "thank you" answers are "Not an answer" and should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you should flag "thank you" posts.  This was an edge case where the edited post looked like something that also frequently gets flagged, a short or duplicate answer.  When the moderator reviewed the flag, it looked like a legitimate (although low-quality) answer.  The non-answer "thank you" post really should not have been edited this way.  The revised answer doesn't add anything to the page.

Comment: Does this include comments? or just "answer posts"?

Comment: @onaclov2000 Just answer posts.  Saying "thanks" in a comment is okay.  If a post accumulates more than a few of these comments go ahead and flag it for clean up, but a single "thanks" doesn't warrant a flag.

Comment: Thank you Bill! I am sure this comment of mine doesn't warrant a flag :)